# Disable pixel grid magnetism (snap) in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids, creative-cloud

In previous Photoshop versions, we were able to move freely anchor points in the document but in Photoshop CC, by default, anchor points follow the pixel grid. I found how to disable it (visually) but the magnetism is always present.

So my question is: How to disable pixel grid magnetism?

[image]

Edit: magnetism options are all disabled

[image]

Comment: I updated my post with "magnetism" options screenshot

Comment: My gif animation have been created on an empty document (not in center) with only one anchor point. It cannot be aligned to another element because there is no other elements. But I checked it, Smart Guides are disabled. It is really a pixel grid magnetism. Thank your for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**I found the solution**: see the screenshot bellow

I don't understand why this option is hidden in preferences panel and why it is enabled by default, his place should be in "snap to" menu and disabled

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that changes things? That pref item has no effect on moving things for me, it only makes the vector tools snap to the pixel grid when *you are dragging out a shape* or using the Pen Tool.

Comment: It works for me: anchor point (creation ([P] key), moves ([A] key) ant transformation ([cmd] + [T] keys)) are no longer "snapped to" the pixel grid. It is the only one option I changed

Comment: hmm... moving [v] still snaps to the pixel grid here.

Comment: Moving tool [V] is not a vector tool, it is a bitmap tool. If you try to move vector, it moves pixels map of the vector shape render, this behavior is normal according to me. To move vector shape, I use [A] key

Comment: I'm aware of the tools. Try moving **anything** with the Move tool... it all still snaps to the pixel grid. The Selection Tool and Direct Selection Tools are editing tools, while the Move tool is designed to, well, move things. You never specified *only vector objects* in your question. In fact, there's no mention of vector at all in your question.

Comment: "Anchor point" is not an implicite vector reference ?

Comment: This only seems to work for me if I have a single anchor point selected. As soon as I select multiple anchor points, it goes back to pixel-snapping.

Comment: Thank you @peterflynn that seems to be the distinction I needed. I was having the exact opposite problem. I had a font glyph I converted to shape so I could move select points _onto_ the grid, but the pixel snapping would constrain all point moves to whole pixel-at-a-time moves (meaning I was always still _off_ the grid). Unchecking that box _and_ only moving one pixel at a time allowed me to move a pixel onto the grid.

Comment: Once you've unchecked that option, you are able to nudge and move less than a pixel if you first use Free Transform on the object in question (ctrl+T on windows)!

Answer (score 3):

It appears there is **no way to disable** the **snap** (magnetism) to the **pixel grid** in Photoshop CC. Looks like perhaps a bug.

Comment: Arf, big regression. Thank you for your help, I don't know if I have to validate your answer, I will do it in few days if there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah - frustrating!!

One ugly workaround - if you're merely trying to position 50% of a pixel, resize your document 150%, snap-position to an odd pixel, resize back, and it will be midway between snap-points then.

Comment: This won't work as the vectors are snapped to the pixel grid by default. Pixel grids are useful in some respects, but not in others.

Answer (score -1):

I know in CS6 you goto  <kbd>View > Snap</kbd>  and click it to disable the snap. This worked for me.

Comment: This answer works to disable snapping to the actual grid if you have it enabled.

Comment: This simply isn't true. You can enable/disable the pixel grid snap in CS6 by using the option at the bottom of the **Preferences** > **General** tab: **Snap Vector Tools and Transforms to Pixel Grid**.