# Photoshop cc - disable pixel snap when select & move multiple anchor points of a shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

When selecting and moving one anchor point, it moves freely.
But selecting multiple points of the same shape and moving them - it snaps to pixel grid.
Anyone know how to disable that and have them move freely?
Thanks!

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21952/disable-pixel-grid-magnetism-snap-in-photoshop-cc

Comment: thanks but that only works for selecting and moving one anchor point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I can really think of, to achieve this, is to use the arrow keys on your keyboard to move the selected points.